# Mabook Pro: replace with display assembly from later model possible?

Tags: macbook-pro, compatibility, laptop-display, spare-parts

Can the display assembly in a `MacBook Pro 15" late 2008` ( `MacBookPro5,1`) be replaced with a display assembly from a later model with identical `Model Number A1286` and size (`15.4"`)?

The APN for the MacBookPro5,1 is `661-4837` or `661-5091`.

Later `A1286` models have partly identical descriptions of the assembly in [Mactracker](https://mactracker.ca/), but have different APNs. Example (that I have an offer for): the MacBookPro8,2 came with assemblies `661-5847`, `661-5849` (hi-res, anti-glare), or `661-5848` (hi-res, glossy).

Answer (score 0):

im not a mac guru or certified apple tech etc. but

i was trying to do pretty much do the same thing with 15in mb pro a1211 (model 2,1)  not the exact same thing, which in the import honda world as doing a frankenstein build, mine was not display but logic board. which i still have yet to start on it. i was wanting to swap  my logic board (because i at time thought or was getting told that my logic board died,) for newer faster version,
  is able to be installed than just buy the original board as the prices on just the boards are pretty similar. to each other.   the major problem i kept having was that the people who own and use apple/mac products, share the same principles in rergards to apple products, much like saab, and porsche enthusiasts have about their cars, which its taboo, or not taboo, ill say it this way, a 20 year old porsche thats not in great shape  and needs repairs etc  is easier to sell and will yeild a higher selling price than the same year model porsche  that lets say has 40000 in engine and appreance type modifications    mainly the exterior styling body kits are the major factor.  same with apple fans, they buy it, then they dont get another till the other is in no way useable anymore. and up to the last model releases that came out uptil jobs died  you never had the need for cannibalisation of prodcuts to repair anothe.

anyway  after many weeks of surfing the web, and a buddy who was an actual apple store apple genius tech.

to do a frankenstein build,  you generally are constrained to the products within that model/version release family ie  like mine   im a model 2,1  so pretty much i could only interchange parts that were from that model line,  thered are exceptions,  but as long as the connecttions match,  and the programing code is same uyou could do it,

Everymac.com is an amazing resource for all things mac apple, macmall, etc,and ive also come across the PROPERIETARY apple repair/service manuals in pdf form that is free to download  may not get an authentically free download right off the bat but most times regardless of what type of manual it is   ive found a true free download at most by the 4th scfreen of web results

so hope that helps